# SSL websocket in php / javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ssl

I am currently working on a real time notification service using websocket using TLS/SSL (wss://).
I have some problem for the handshake between the browser and the server. Everything works fine with a server and a client in php but when I use the JS's websocket to connect to the server, it fails because *I don't know how to handle the handshake in server-side (from a browser).*
So far my code for the server is :

```
$host = '127.0.0.1';
$port = '9000';
$null = NULL;

$context = stream_context_create();

// local_cert must be in PEM format
stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'local_cert', "cert.pem");
stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'local_pk', "key.pem");
// Pass Phrase (password) of private key
stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'passphrase', "test");
stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'allow_self_signed', true);
stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'verify_peer', false);

// Create the server socket
$server = stream_socket_server('ssl://' . $host . ':' . $port, $errno, $errstr, STREAM_SERVER_BIND | STREAM_SERVER_LISTEN, $context);

if ($server == false) {
    die ("Could no create the server.");
}

//start endless loop

while (true) {
    $buffer = '';
    print "waiting...";
    $client = stream_socket_accept($server);
    var_dump($client);
    print "accepted " . stream_socket_get_name($client, true) . "\n";
    if ($client) {
        stream_set_blocking($client, true); 
        // TODO : handshaking
        stream_set_blocking($client, false);
        
        // Respond to php client (test only)
        /*fwrite($client, "200 OK HTTP/1.1\r\n"
            . "Connection: close\r\n"
            . "Content-Type: text/html\r\n"
            . "\r\n"
            . "Hello World!");
        fclose($client);*/
    } else {
        print "error.\n";
    }
}
```

Nothing is stated about the SSL handshake on the [RFC WebSocket](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455).

If anyone has some idea on how to implement a handshake, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Nothing is stated about the SSL handshake on the RFC WebSocket.

`wss://` is just `ws://` inside a SSL connection, same as HTTPS is just HTTP inside a SSL connection. There is nothing special, i.e. you just need to speak the WebSocket protocol on the SSL stream after the successful SSL handshake.

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification. However from wikipedia, the server returns `HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols
Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: HSmrc0sMlYUkAGmm5OPpG2HaGWk=
Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: chat`
this for `ws://` socket, shouldn't I return something different for a `wss://` websocket ?

Comment: @AlexandreChambet: no, the request send for the upgrade is the same and the response is the same too. The only difference is that one is communicating over a plain TCP connection while the other over an SSL stream. Exactly the same as with HTTP vs. HTTPS.

Comment: Thank you, I will think about it.